# best practice on reading bash output from C code (currently redirecting to files and reading them)

Tags: c, system-calls, io-redirection

I want to use my Linux `system()` calls for many things that I can't do (at least can't do as easily, from my C code). I'm using output redirection into files, reading the file, and then deleting it.

**Is there a better way?** (I thought of pipes, but files kind of the same to me, and easier to implement, IMO)

---

This is my example code for getting number of files in CWD:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *file_name = "my_file.txt";
    FILE *f;
    char command[256] = "ls -l | wc -l > ";
    char buffer[256];
    int err = 0;

    strcat(command, file_name);
    err |= system(command);

    f = fopen(file_name, "r");
    fgets(buffer, 256, f);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    err |= remove(file_name);

    if(err) printf("error occured\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/popen.html

Comment: You want `popen()`.

Comment: Why is popen better than files?

Comment: Because it doesn't create files? That seemed to be what you were asking for.

Comment: If you want to get the number of files in a directory, why are you using `system()` and this convoluted pipeline  at all? Use `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`closedir()` to count the entries.

Comment: A pipe is better than a file because (1) you don't have to remember to delete it afterwards, (2) it easily allows the producer and consumer to run concurrently, (3) it allows the transfer of more data than would fit on disk, and (4) it may be more efficient.  (For a toy example none of these may matter much, but they can make a big difference for real problems, in practice.)

Comment: Thanks @Steve Summit! That was what I was looking for